# How to make use of variable on a function

Tags: mysql, function, stored-functions

I need to make a stored function:

This is my code

```
SELECT count(Dominio) FROM Thogar WHERE DOMINIO='%'
```

I need to make a stored function where I will write a letter between (U,C,R) and the function will replace the **%** in the previous code with the selected letter.

How can I do it? Thanks!

Got it working

```
CREATE FUNCTION `Buscar`(`param` CHAR(1))
    RETURNS INT
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE res INT;
    SELECT count(Dominio) INTO res FROM Thogar WHERE DOMINIO=param;
    RETURN res;
END

    Call buscar('C')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on writing a leteer between UCR, I answered with an option for a function with user input

Comment: I'll try: 
As far as I know, you start a function by using the call command, like this
CALL simpleproc(@a); 
I need to create a function where I can say what letter I want the function to use in the code

For example, I call the function; Call function(C)
So the function will make this query; SELECT count(Dominio) FROM Thogar WHERE DOMINIO='C'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS myFunc;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION myFunc(
    param CHAR(1)
) RETURNS INT;
BEGIN
    DECLARE res INT;
    SELECT count(Dominio) INTO res FROM Thogar WHERE DOMINIO=param;
    RETURN res;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I got it now! With your help and playing with Heidi Software, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If You want to make stored function with only one sql query, 
I don't see any normal reason for it.

It will not give You performance gain.

How about simplification?

You can create view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_dominio_counters AS 
SELECT Dominio, count(Dominio) AS counter FROM Thogar GROUP BY Dominio
```

And then use it:

```
SELECT counter FROM v_dominio_counters WHERE Dominio = 'U' LIMIT 1;
```

It will always keep for You ready to use counters that is handy when You have huge table.